# knockout dynamic binding issue

Tags: binding, knockout.js

Consider the following ViewModel that is generated through the knockout mapping plugin.

```
var originalData = {

"QuoteSelectedViewModel": {
  "ProductName": "Select",      
  "CoverQuotesViewModel": [
     {
        "Code": 1,
        "Label": "Première Assistance 24h/24 (GRATUITE)",
        "IsMandatory": true,
        "IsSelected": true,            
        "DependsOn": []
     },
     {
        "Code": 2,
        "Label": "Assistance PLUS 24h/24",
        "IsMandatory": false,
        "IsSelected": false,          
        "DependsOn": []
     },
      {
        "Code": 8,
        "Label": "Heurts Animaux / Force de la Nature",
        "IsMandatory": false,
        "IsSelected": false,        
        "DependsOn": [
           2
        ]
     },
  ]}
}

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(originalData);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


<div data-bind="with: QuoteSelectedViewModel">
selected quote is : <span data-bind="text: ProductName"></span>
 <!-- ko foreach: CoverQuotesViewModel -->
<br/>    
  <div data-bind: if: IsVisible>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected"></input>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Label, enable: IsSelected"></input>
  </div>
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Now, I would like to hide the div when IsVisible returns false. IsVisible does not exist yet, and it should be a computed observable function on each element of the CoverQuotesViewModel array.

How do I generate this computed observable function on each element ?

Thanks

***[EDIT]***
I've added a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/graphicsxp/fpKWM/

[EDIT2]
Actually knockout document is clear about how to do that:

> Of course, inside the create callback you can do another call to
>   ko.mapping.fromJS if you wish. A typical use-case might be if you want
>   to augment the original JavaScript object with some additional
>   computed observables:
>
> var myChildModel = function(data) {
>       ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
>
> ```
> this.nameLength = ko.computed(function() {
>     return this.name().length;
> }, this); }
> ```

**[EDIT]**

Here's the full code following Paul's suggestion:
(getQuotesSuccess is an AJAX success handler)

```
viewModel.getQuotesSuccess = function (result) {
var myCoverQuotesViewModel = function (data, parent) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

    self.IsVisible = ko.computed(function () {
        var visible = true;
        if (self.DependsOn().length > 0) {
            $.each(self.DependsOn(), function (index, value) {
                var dependency = viewModel.QuoteSelectedViewModel().CoverQuotesViewModel.filterByProperty("Code", value);
                if (dependency().length > 0) {
                    visible = visible & dependency()[0].IsSelected();
                } else {
                    visible = false;
                }
            });
        }

        return visible;

    }, this);
}

var mapping = {
    'CoverQuotesViewModel': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new myCoverQuotesViewModel(options.data, options.parent);
        }
    }
}

  ko.mapping.fromJS(result, mapping, viewModel);
};
```

Comment: Exactly what logic do you want IsVisible to work off?

Comment: let's assume the logic of IsVisible is irrelevant to the problem. It should return true or false. The issue is that I don't know how to generate dynamically this computed observable function on each element of the array.

Comment: See my answer for how you can loop over each of the objects in your array. Is that not what you're after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, reverting back to my earlier answer, with your modifications, so anyone else looking at this answer actually gets the correct version!

You need to create a child viwe model, and use the mapping plugin to populate it automatically, then add in your computed observable:

```
function CoverQuotesViewModel(data)
{
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    // Copy the data to each property.
    self.IsVisible = ko.computed(function()
    {
            // your logic for each quote
    });
}
```

Then you need to use a create map for the mapping of the main view model, and in this you create your child view model:

```
var mapping = {
    'CoverQuotesViewModel': {
        create: function(options) {
            var model = new CoverQuotesViewModel(options.data);
            return model;
        }
    }
}
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

You don't need to pass `this` into the computed, as you are referencing self, which is your stored version of this.

Comment: the IsVisible function should be created on each element of the Array, not at the root level.

Comment: that's great, it's working as expected. However, it is pretty inconvenient having to map by hand all the remaining properties. Is there any way I can keep the automatic mapping while adding the IsVisible computed observable by hand ?

Comment: You could try this updated answer, though I don't know if this will work!

Comment: thanks, but it does not work. The IsVisible property is correctly added to CoverQuotesViewModel but all other properties are gone. Any idea what I can do ?

Comment: Hmm, according to the documentation (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) it should work. I think you will need to add the other properties to the CoverQuotesViewModel class, have you done that?

Comment: ok, that's what I understood then. But I was hoping there'd be a way around it, that would save having to type all the properties by hand. What's the point of using the mapping plugin otherwise ? I find it strange that I can't map all the properties automatically and then add one more (IsVisible) dynamically.

Comment: Paul, I think I've found out, it's written clearly in the document how to do it... I'm not at work now, but I'll try tomorrow (see edit) I think I may have missed the curly brackets as parameter of the mapping function.

Comment: Funnily enough, I've just updated my answer with what I think you want, and it appears to work. :)

Comment: Ah, good to know that! Did you use this with my origanal answer with the child view model set up as a function, or with my final answer?

Comment: with the child view model set up as a function :)

Comment: So did you have to declare the observables manually in the child view model, or did you get round that?

Comment: @user1098555 I've updated my answer with your actual final solution, though I've tidied it up a little, and left out the actual implementation of IsVisible, as I doubt that would be of any interest to anyone else. :)