# Knockout Mapping - Customize Create with Nested Objects

Tags: knockout.js, mapping

I'm running into an issue with KnockoutJS's mapping plugin where I need to do the following:

1. Customize the mapping creation of an object
2. Customize the mapping creation of an array of nested objects from #1.

In this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5cfa3/) I am trying have the *children* properly mapped to their custom creation.  The expected result is that each of the *children* have the added *description* property.  From the fiddle, the result should read:

- Adam Smith
- Bob is 5 years old
- Chris is 7 years old

I can demonstrate the expected behaviour in this this [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Py7P/1/).  Notice that in this code I must have two data sets, with the first having an empty array of children objects.  The following line of code will cause the customized creation of child objects:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(additionalData, parentMapping, viewModel);
```

Unfortunately, this requires both having empty initial *children* and mapping twice.  This is not acceptable as the code in reality has a much deeper hierarchy.

In addition to the above, I've tried adding the following code in the parentMapping:

```
var mapping = { 'ignore': ["children"] };
var innerModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, mapping);
//for brevity
innerModel.children = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data.children, childMapping);
```

This has the effect of mapping the *children* objects on the initial mapping.  However, all subsequent mappings the *children* property is ignored.

Is there a way to customize the creation of both a parent and child object with Knockout Mapping?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this any use to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480316/knockout-dynamic-binding-issue/15480602?noredirect=1#comment21977967_15480602

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/5cfa3/23/

```
var viewModel = {};

var data = {
  id: "1",
  firstName: 'Adam',
  lastName: "Smith",
  children: [ {id: "2", name: "Bob", age: 5}, {id: "3", name: "Chris", age: 7 }]
};

var Parent = function(data){
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this)
};

var mapping = {
  create:function(options){
    var parent = new Parent(options.data);
    parent.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return parent.firstName() + " " + parent.lastName();
    });
    return parent;
  },
  'children': {
     create: function(options) {
         options.data.description = ko.computed(function(){
             return options.data.name + " is " + options.data.age + " years old ";
         });
         return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);         
     }
   }
};

viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/an40fp6y/
The one posted by Darussian six years ago isn't working due to https issues.