# Trouble in Knockout when mapping data in nested observableArray

Tags: javascript, web, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have trouble trying to map data in a nested observableArray (timeSlots).
When I fill my participants observableArray it works just fine. I bet I have to do something special when it's nested.

I'm new to *Knockout* so not sure what I am doing wrong.
I've been looking at the documentation to no avail, especially at:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

**Here is my code: (EDITED)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var TimeSlot = function (startTime, endTime) {
    var self = this;
    self.startTime = startTime;
    self.endTime = endTime;
};

var Participant = function (id, timeSlots) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = id;
    self.roomName = ko.observable();
    self.timeSlots = ko.observableArray();

    var timeSlotVMs = _.map(timeSlots, function(ts) {
        return new TimeSlot(ts.startTime, ts.endTime);
    });

    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.timeSlots(), timeSlotVMs);
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.participants = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.addPerson = function () {
         var data = '{"TimeSlot":[{"startTime":"05:23","endTime":"06:32"},
                     {"startTime":"10:23","endTime":"11:32"}]}';
         var partViewModel = new Participant(self.selectedValue().Id(), data.TimeSlot);
         self.participants.push();
    };
};



var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

</script>
```

**And HTML if needed:**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: viewModel.participants">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: roomName"></td>

        <td data-bind="foreach: viewModel.participants.timeSlots">
                <span data-bind="text: startTime"></span>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout Mapping - Customize Create with Nested Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526417/knockout-mapping-customize-create-with-nested-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var TimeSlot = function (startTime, endTime) {
    var self = this;
    self.startTime = startTime;
    self.endTime = endTime;
};

var Participant = function (id, timeSlots) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = id;
    self.roomName = ko.observable();
    self.timeSlots = ko.observableArray();

    var timeSlotVMs = _.map(timeSlots, function(ts) {
        return new TimeSlot(ts.startTime, ts.endTime); 
    });
    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.timeSlots(), timeSlotVMs);        
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.participants = ko.observableArray();

    self.addPerson = function () {
         var data = {
             TimeSlot: [
               {startTime:"05:23",endTime:"06:32"},
               {startTime:"10:23",endTime:"11:32"}
            ]
         };
         var partViewModel = new Participant(123, data.TimeSlot);
         self.participants.push(partViewModel);
    };
};
```

**I used [lodash](http://lodash.com) library function 'map', to create array of viewmodels.**

Also, you have error in your layout. Use timeSlots instead viewModel.participants.timeSlots:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: participants">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: roomName"></td>

        <td data-bind="foreach: timeSlots">
            <span data-bind="text: startTime"></span>
        </td>
    </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: I had to modify to var timeSlotVMs = _.map(timeSlots, function(ts) {
            return new TimeSlot(ts.startTime, ts.endTime);
        });
to make it run, however I am still not getting it to work

Comment: Can you update your question with new code? Or create it [here](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Removed the "viewModel.participants.timeSlots" and just wrote timeSlots. Still not working I'm afraid.
<td data-bind="foreach: timeSlots"><span data-bind="text: startTime"></span></td>

Comment: I've updated my answer again and created a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRye2/2/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It works with your solution thanks.