# knockout recursive mapping issue

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

this post is a follow-up to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480316/knockout-dynamic-binding-issue).

I've updated the code as followed:

```
viewModel.getQuotesSuccess = function (result) {

    var myCoverQuotesViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.Childs = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data.Childs, function (c) {
        return new myCoverQuotesViewModel(c);
    }));

    self.selectedChild = ko.observable();
    self.showChildren = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.selectedChild()
        && self.selectedChild().Childs().length > 0;
    });



var mapping = {
    'CoverQuotes': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new myCoverQuotesViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(result, mapping, viewModel);
```

};

The viewModel would look something like this:

```
var viewModel = {

     CoverQuotes: [{id: 1, label:'test', Childs:[{id: 2, label:'child1'}]]
};
```

So in a nutshell, I have an array of CoverQuotes, which each element also contains an array of CoverQuotes (and so on).

The problem I have with this mapping, is with the Childs observable array. When calling:

```
 return new myCoverQuotesViewModel(options.data);
```

for the main object, it works fine. However when calling the constructor from within th arrayMap function, then that line:

```
 ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
```

doesn't do anything.

As a result, nested children are assigned the properties selectedChild and showChildren but they are missing all others (like id and label in this example).

What am I missing so the mapping also works for children  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem using a recursive custom mapping

```
viewModel.getQuotesSuccess = function (result) {
    var myCoverQuotesViewModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;

        var mappingChildren = {
            'Childs': {
                create: function (options) {
                    return new myCoverQuotesViewModel(options.data);
                }
            }
        }

        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingChildren, self);


        self.selectedChild = ko.observable();
        self.showChildren = ko.computed(function () {
            return self.selectedChild() && self.selectedChild().Childs().length > 0;
        });

        self.IsVisible = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                var visible = true;
                if (self.DependsOn().length > 0) {
                    $.each(self.DependsOn(), function (index, value) {
                        var dependency = viewModel.QuoteSelectedViewModel().CoverQuotes.filterByProperty("Code", value);
                        if (dependency().length > 0) {
                            visible = visible & dependency()[0].IsSelected();
                        } else {
                            visible = false;
                        }
                    });
                }

                return visible;
            },
            deferEvaluation: true
        }, this);
    }

    var mapping = {
        'CoverQuotes': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new myCoverQuotesViewModel(options.data);
            }
        }
    }

    ko.mapping.fromJS(result, mapping, viewModel);
};
```

Comment: would you not have achieved the same goal by placing your mappingChildren options outside of your VM? Actually, you should be able to copy the 'Childs' property of mappingChildren to mapping and just retro the child mapping directive over to ko.mapping.fromJS(data,mapping,self). Since data includes a 'Childs' property, the mapping should use the 'Childs' property, even though the mapping is the same.