# Knockout automapped array with formatted (computed?) column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, crud, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a CRUD single page using Knockout, everything works OK, I get the data from a JSON call, it fills an automapped observable array with the list of objects.
I can add or edit single items in that array.

The issue comes with formatting a currency (numeric) column I show in the table with the list of objects. I have tried using js functions, in a lot of ways but the formatted currency amount of the table does not update when I update an item.
If I use a binding for formatting the field then I can't edit it because it converts into a String.

What I need is a one-way binded (auto updated) formatted column for my currency column.  But I can't create a computed column right away because I'm using an automapped array of objects.  I tried adding the computed using the example in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html, but I don't know how to use it with an mapped array.

My viewmodel is something like this:

```
//--Accounts - Viewmodel Knockout
function accountViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.accounts = ko.observableArray();  //this is the list of objects
    self.account = ko.observable();  //single item for creating or editing

    //--get list------
    self.getAccounts = function () {
        $.postJSON(appURL + 'Accounts/GetList', function (data) {  
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data.Records, {}, self.accounts);

        });

    };

    self.getAccounts();
}
```

Each account item have fields like:
-Id
-Name
-Balance  <-- this is the column I want to format

Using it in the page:

```
<table data-bind="visible: accounts().length > 0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Id</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Balance</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="accounts" data-bind="foreach: accounts">
<tr>
    <td><span data-bind="text: Id"></span></td>
    <td><a href="" data-bind="text: Name,  click: $root.getdetails" style="display:block;"></a></td>
    <td style="text-align:right;">
        <span data-bind="text: formatCurrency(Balance), css: { negative: Balance() < 0, positive: Balance() > 0 }"></span>

    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

formatCurrency is just a js function for formatting the number:

```
formatCurrency = function (value) {
    debugger;
    if (value!=undefined)
        return "$" + withCommas(value().toFixed(2));
    //had to use value() instead of value, because of toFixed
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate for how to use the mapping plugin and have a computed on a mapped object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480316/knockout-dynamic-binding-issue/15480602#15480602

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the text to the return value of a function (`text: formatCurrency(Balance)`) it only runs once. It's not an observable, so it's value will never update again. What you need is a true-blue computed observable. In order to get that, you'll have to customize the mapping. So simply create a view model for your individual account object, and then map your returned data onto that.

```
var SingleAccountViewModel = function (account) {
    var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(account);

    model.FormattedBalance = ko.computed(function () {
        return formattedCurrency(model.Balance);
    });

    return model;
}
```

Then when you get your data back from your AJAX response:

```
$.postJSON(appURL + 'Accounts/GetList', function (data) {  
    self.accounts($.map(data.Records, SingleAccountViewModel));
});
```

The jQuery.map method will iterate through the array and return a new array composed of the return values of the function passed. In this case, that's your view model, which will now have a `FormattedBalance` computed on it that you can bind to.

Comment: Just implemented that, now I got the computed column in my model. But FormattedBalance still it won't update when updating Balance

Comment: This is an issue with using foreach with an observableArray. Only changes to the array itself trigger an update, not changes to the objects *in* the array. So you have to trigger a change to the array to force the value update. The lazy way of doing it is to simply get and then set the value of the observableArray, which will update the entire block. This SO question has a slightly more finessed way of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861106/updating-an-observablearray-does-not-update-ui

Comment: Sorry, after implementing the computed column, I didn't notice I was getting another error after modifying the Balance field. Knockout, for some reason, was converting it to a String, so I was getting a "object does not have a method toFixed" inside the formatCurrency function. I worked it out by explicitly converting the value to float.  Now it works! Thanks!